# emacs flycheck errors and display issues

Tags: c, emacs, flycheck

I'm trying to get used to Emacs, I'm coding in C for my school. So, I installed flycheck to check for potential compliation errors. However, I encounter several problems. Here's the message I get when I test flycheck with the c/c++-gcc checker : [flycheck buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LAr7.png)

I have two issues there : 
 - first, flycheck claims the checker "returned a 1 exit code without errors" depsite the fact it actually did, and it's even displaying it right after ! 
 - secondly, it does not seem to be able to display quotes correctly, the only thing displayed are their unicode escape sequences.
I can't find out why those issues are present. Can anybody help me on this ?

Comment: Why not just try actually compiling your code and using the compiler errors?
They will be more useful and more important than this tool.

Comment: Flycheck actually takes output from the compiler and displays it below the buffer, so it's the exact same errors that are displayed.

Comment: And does compiling in GCC directly produces these same errors?

Comment: It does. But I use it so I can spot directly dumb errors as typos in variable names, etc.
Overall, it checks on the fly when writing code, so it's way less tedious than compiling and then correcting every error.

Comment: I get that :), I mean is GCC also producing these errors on this exact code? If so it's an error with your code and not with flycheck.

Comment: this question: 1) is using an external link rather than posting text on the question 2) is about the output from some tool rather than a programming problem.

Comment: I fixed both my problems by setting my environment language to UTF-8. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

fixed both my problems by setting my environment language to UTF-8.